# Query works fine in Managment Studio but throws error from batch file/CMD prompt

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I have this sql query:

```
CREATE USER [myDomain\myUser] FROM LOGIN [myDomain\myUser];
```

works just fine when I execute from the SQL Management Studio. That is, it created a user successfully for the DB I "use"d before (`USE [myDB];`)

I am running the same query from a dos batch file:

```
sqlcmd -E -S localhost\myInstance -Q "CREATE USER [myDomain\myUser] FROM LOGIN [myDomain\myUser];"
```

It throws error:

```
Msg 15023, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
User, group, or role 'myDomain\myUser' already exists in the current database.
```

I initially thought something must be wrong with my script and then tried to run it from command prompt. It threw the same error.

Any idea what could cause this, please?

Comment: The user you are attempting to create (`FHNET\fhstest`) already exists, as the error message clearly states. You cannot create users, groups or roles with a name that is identical to an existing user, group or role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for the DB I "use"d before (USE [myDB];)

You do not specify a DB to use in the SQLCMD invocation. Type `sqlcmd /?` or read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) how to specify the database.

Comment: ` -d db_name ` Sure let me try that option now and see how it behaves. Thank you!

Comment: It worked now. It did not throw the error as before from my batch file. Thank you!